# How to design a top-1 select algorithm to maximize a variable and minimize other variable?

Tags: sorting, selection-problem

I want to implement an algorithm thats select the best group, which maximize the variable A and minimize the variable B.

For instance, I have the following groups:

G1 - A = 10 B = 2

G2 - A = 10 B = 3

G3 - A = 12 B = 1

G4 - A = 10 B = 4

and so on...

One solution could be the sorting the groups by A and resolve ties by selecting the B, but this is not the case here.. it is a tradeoff. I need to select a group with a good tradeoff.
How can I do this tradeoff? any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not answerable.  Only you can tell us what counts as a good tradeoff, for you.  You need to pick a single objective function that combines A and B into a single quantity.  We can't tell you how to do that, because that will depend on what makes sense for your particular application domain.

For instance, maybe it's best to choose the item with the highest value of $A/B$.  Or maybe it's best to choose the item with highest value of $A-B$.  Or maybe its' best to choose the item with highest value of $100A-B$, or $A-100B$, or $A + 1/B$, or $100A + 1/B$.  We can't tell you.  You will need to analyze your application to determine what the right objective function is.  Take a look at your specific application and understand what is a measure of benefit or cost that is meaningful in your application domain, and then figure out how that depends on $A$ and $B$ ... and use that as the objective function to maximize.

Comment: thank you for the comment. It helped me a lot... well in fact, I am implementing it from a paper that does not explain in detail how this tradeoff is chosen. It only says that we can pick a group with A value that is a little bit lesser than the highest A value, then, it would prioritize the minimum value of B.... maybe minimize the B value has more priority than maximize A. For this case, what would you recommend?

Comment: It is unclear still, what "more priority means"? It spans from: search for minimum B, to in case of equal sums choose one with the smallest B. If you implement something from paper: give us link to it, describe what A and B represent. In the worst case you can apply all functions that D.W. described and pick one (or return all of them).